# I can't let the iron flow out of my smeltery and my stencil table doesn't work!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hexxit

I want to work with the smeltery, but everytime I burn iron it can't flow out of the seared faucet and when I try to stencil a pattern (kreativ-mode), the stencil table doesn't work. Is it a bug or has it something to do with my options?

Answer (score 4):

To get liquid metals out of your smeltery, you need to use casts made of either gold or aluminum brass on a casting table that is placed under the seared faucet.

To make the casts, first smelt either gold or aluminum, copper, and tin. While they are smelting, place the item you want to make a cast of (a pick head, a tool rod, etc.  Ingots are the most useful, in my humble opinion) on to the casting table. When you right-click the faucet, the gold or aluminum brass will pour around the item on the table, making a cast once it cools. Right-click to take your item back, right-click again to take the cast.

Once you have that, place the cast you want back onto the casting table. Smelt the metal you want in the smeltery. When it is done smelting, click on the faucet to fill the cast with the liqid metal of your choice.

NOTE: Make sure to have enough of that metal in the smeltery to fill the cast. I.E. if it takes 8 cobblestone to make a hammer head on the stencil table, it will take 8 ingots worth of iron to make an iron hammer head.

Comment: Did aluminum brass change to include tin in the newest version? I remember it being 2 aluminum ingots and one copper, but no tin.